# How to delete 2d array?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

How do I delete this allocated pointer?

```
int (*foo)[4] = new int[100][4];
```

Is it just :

```
delete[] foo;
```

Comment: You're using `new T[]` with `T` being `int[100]`. Therefore, you need `delete[]`, like any other `T`.

Comment: @chris, isn't the type `int[4]` actually? `int (*foo)[4]` declares a pointer to array-of-4-int, then you allocate 100 such arrays.

Comment: @vsoftco, Oops, that's right. Not sure why I put `int[100]`.

Comment: First I am not sure if that`s how you initialize a double pointer. Second, its seems you have a pointer foo; that points to four pointers. To avoid memory leak you have to delete all pointers and not just one. So you need to: delete foo[0]; delete foo[1]; delete foo[2]; delete foo[3]; and then delete foo; All these are pointers.

Comment: @Juniar, it is not a double pointer, it is a pointer to a data type defined as `int[4]` (that occupies 4 contiguous ints), so in the memory looks like `{X X X X} -> {X X X X} -> ... 100 times ... -> {X X X X }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have allocated an array you have to use operator delete[]

```
delete []foo;
```

That it would be more clear you can rewrite the code snippet the following way

```
typedef int T[4];

T *foo = new T[100];

delete []foo;
```